# How to convert Days in dataframe column to an integer in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column in my dataframe (it has many more rows but they are all in this format):

```
1st Year Score
365 days 00:00:00
163 days 00:00:00
365 days 00:00:00
143 days 00:00:00
365 days 00:00:00
365 days 00:00:00
52 days 00:00:00
```

And I want to produce this:

```
1st Year Score
365 
163 
365 
143 
365 
365 
52
```

I have tried the following:

```
data['1st Year Score'] = data['1st Year Score'].dt.days()

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

I also tried:

```
data['1st Year Score'] = pd.to_datetime(data['1st Year Score'],errors='coerce')
```

which deleted everything in my 1st year column.  Let me know how to fix this, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try via `pd.to_timedelta()`:

```
df['1st Year Score']=pd.to_timedelta(df['1st Year Score']).dt.days
```

output of `df['1st Year Score']`:

```
0    365
1    163
2    365
3    143
4    365
5    365
6     52
Name: 1st Year Score, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> df["1st Year Score"].str.split(" days").str[0].astype(int)
0    365
1    163
2    365
3    143
4    365
5    365
6     52
Name: 1st Year Score, dtype: int32
```